# Reflection Proxy- Visibility from class loader problem

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, proxy-classes

I'm attempting to:
1) Load an interface and implementation class from a given file location
2) Create a Proxy object with reflection that matches the interface, and directs all calls to the implementation class

This is later used for testing purposes using JUnit.

**The Problem:**
However, I seem to be having problems when I try to create the proxy object. I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface Testing.Testable is not visible from class loader
...at Core.ProxyFactory.createProxy(ProxyFactory.java:26)
```

The line in question is as follows:

```
Object obj = Proxy.newProxyInstance(implementationClass.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{interfaceClass}, forwarder);
```

**Class loading the right way?**
I am loading the classes that I need using a URLClassLoader. The snippet for this is as follows:

```
URL url = new File(path).toURI().toURL();
URL[] urlList = {url};
// Create loader and load
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urlList);
Class loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass (classname);
return loadedClass;
```

However, is this correct? This snippet gets repeated for each class file, and so I believe each time a new class loader is created. Could this be causing my problem? How can I resolve this?

*Thanks in advance for any help you can give*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved...**
I was correct in my concerns that I was loading the classes in the wrong way. Because the classes depend on each other (e.g. one class uses another), they need to belong to the *same* classloader, or a child therefore of.

This problem can be solved by replacing use of the URLClassLoader with:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urlList);
Class[] classes = new Class[classNames.length];
for (int i = 0; i<classNames.length; i++) {
  classes[i] = classLoader.loadClass(classNames[i]);
}
```

This allows you to load multiple classes using the same classloader, and seems to solve the problem!